# How to properly implement async or await operation in the loop - nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodejs so please excuse if I miss the obvious. 
I'm currently struggling with the async operations for my code. it goes like this. I run express framework to call specific URL that calls external REST server to get some information on the objects. I don't have problem with basic operation where I process REST response, parse JSON and pass the info to EJS view-engine to render HTML page. 
However, I'm having issue with one particular process where after I got my REST response (list of volumes) and then I want to run another REST call to get more details about each volume (in a loop). After the retrieval is done, I want to call EJS to render page with list of volumes and their details.
Here is my code:

```
function listVolumes(req, res) {
        var element = 'volume';
        var element_list= [];
        var output_json = [];
        var options = { method: 'GET',
                url: MY_ENV.MY_URL + '/v2/volumes',
          headers: 
           { 
             'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
             'X-Auth-Token': MY_ENV.MY_TOKEN,
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/json' }
        }
            request(options) // using request-promise
                .then(function (body) {
                output_json = JSON.parse(body); // parsing array of JSON objects from REST server
                if (Object.keys(output_json).length > 0){
                    for (var i in output_json.list) { // iterating over list of JSON objects
                        var volume_id = output_json.list[i];
                        console.log(i, ': ' , JSON.stringify(volume_id, null, 3));
                        getVolumeDetails(volume_id, function callback(volume){ // getting volume details
                            element_list.push({ id: volume_id, name: volume.name, size: volume.size, state: volume.state });
                        });
                    }
                    res.render('listVolumes', {element, element_list, output_json }); // calling ejs view-engine to render html page
                } else console.log('No volumes found.');
            })
                .catch (function (error) {
                    console.log('Got error while listing ' + element , error);
                });
}
function getVolumeDetails(volume_id, callback){
    var options = { method: 'GET',
            url: MY_ENV.MY_URL + '/v2/volumes/' + volume_id,
      headers: 
       { 
         'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
         'X-Auth-Token': MY_ENV.MY_TOKEN,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json' } };
    request(options)
        .then(function (body) {
            volume = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log('got volume: ' , volume.name , volume.size, volume.state);
            callback(volume);
        })
        .catch (function (error) {
        console.log('Got error while reading volume: ' + volume_id , error.message);
        }); 

}
app.get('/list/volumes', listVolumes);
```

It is obvious that when I call EJS it renders the HTML page and later on I'm getting console messages for getVolumeDetails() because of the async nature of javascript.
I've read many articles about using request-promise, async.each, async wait, callbacks and still struggle to understand how to make it work. I don't mind to wait few seconds for the loop to finish getting all volumes details, to populate my element_list with array of items I want to show on HTML page. 
Can you help me please to guide what construct to use and how  ?

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [async.queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue)?
You can also try out recursion.

Comment: I made some changes and was able to async.each() to work but I find that it never finishes, i.e. never runs the 3rd function after all iteratee functions have run. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

here are my modifications:

```
function listVolumes(req, res) {
    var element = 'volume';
    var element_list= [];
    var output_json = [];
    var options = { method: 'GET',
            url: MY_ENV.MY_URL + '/v2/volumes',
      headers: 
       { 
         'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
         'X-Auth-Token': MY_ENV.MY_TOKEN,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json' }
    }
    request(options)
        .then(function (body) {
        output_json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('Raw body of listVolumes(): \n' , body);
        if (Object.keys(output_json).length > 0){
            async.each(output_json.list, function (volume_id, callback){
                options.url = MY_ENV.MY_URL + '/v2/volumes/' + volume_id;
                request(options)
                    .then(function (body) {
                        var volume = JSON.parse(body);
                        console.log('got callback: ' , volume.id, volume.name , volume.size, volume.state);
                        element_list.push({ id: volume.id, name: volume.name, size: volume.size, state: volume.state });
                        callback(null);
                    })
                    .catch (function (error) {
                    console.log('Got error while reading volume: ' + volume_id , error.message);
                    });
            }, 
            function (err){
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error occured: ', err);
                } else {
                    console.log('All done...Element list length: ', element_list.length); // this never runs... why???
                }
                res.render('listVolumes', {element, element_list, output_json });
            });
        } else console.log('No volumes found.');
    })
    .catch (function (error) {
        console.log('Got error while listing ' + element , error);
    });
}
```

so it never runs the code in the function(err) where I put comment `// this never runs... why???`

Comment: I figured out that one of the async calls was failing, so it didn't fire last callback(). so I added another callback() after processing error and that did finish it.
`.catch (function (error) {
 callback();
});`

Comment: So I'm guessing there was a callback needed to take care of the errors?

Comment: Yes! without that callback, it would not finish and never called the rendering engine